# Activator.getImageDescriptor(path) returns null even though plugin.xml makes use of identical path for icons

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In a subclass of `StyledCellLabelProvider`, I have a line like this:

```
ImageDescriptor d = Activator.getImageDescriptor("/icons/sample.gif");
```

However, the variable `d` is always `null`.  Strangely, the image shows up correctly in the upper left corner of a View when I specify the exact same path in `plugin.xml`:

```
  <view
        name="Message"
        allowMultiple="true"
        icon="/icons/sample.gif"
        class="com.myapp.views.EmailView"
        id="com.myapp.gui.emailView">
  </view>
```

The path of this image in my project is the standard location of `<project>/icons/sample.gif`, and the plugin source code is in `<project>/src`.

Frustratingly, the sample Plugin project "RCP Mail Template" uses (successfully) an identical function to obtain a reference to an `ImageDescriptor`:

```
ImageDescriptor d = Activator.getImageDescriptor("/icons/sample.gif");
```

Could there be something wrong with my plugin configuration that would cause images to not be found when referenced programmatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

But the static `getImageDescriptor` methods of *your* `Activator` class and "RCP Mail Template"'s `Activator` class are different. Perhaps you are using incorrect plugin ID there?

Comment: You're right. The `PLUGIN_ID` field in my `Activator` class was out of sync with what I had specified as the ID in Overview tab of the plugin (aka the `Bundle-SymbolicName` field in the `MANIFEST.MF` file).